# É possível adicionar elemento nessa lista dentro do for?

Tags: python

Na tentativa de deixar o código python mais reduzido, gerei essa lista no `enumerate`. O problema é que ela não possui um nome. Como eu poderia adicionar um novo elemento ou excluir sem ter o nome da lista para referenciar?

```
for index_a, valor in enumerate(list(range(5))):
```

Comment: @Max: qual a relação de funções lambda com esse caso? A pessoa está aprendendo programação e com dúvidas sobre o uso básico de variáveis. Mesmo que funções lambda servissem pra algo nesse caso, o que não acontece, só faria sentido cita-la snuma resposta completa detalhando muito bem o seu uso.

Answer (score 0):

Se você vai precisar acessar uma lista, coloque ela numa variável.

Usar direto o range num `for`, com ou sem `enumerate`, vai criar uma sequência que vai ser usada só pelo `for`.

No caso desse código seria só:

```
minha_lista = list(range(5))

for index_a, valor in enumerate(minha_lista):
     ...
```

E a lista completa fica disponível na variável `minha_lista`.

Também, do jeito que você estava usando, não tem sentido 
converter a chamada do range numa lista - não precisa do `list`,
se for usar o resultado só no `for`:

```
for index_a, valor in enumerate(range(5)):
    ...
```

(tudo bem que nesse caso o uso do enumerate é bem supérfluo, já que os números gerados pelo range vão ser exatamente os mesmos que os índices gerados pelo enumerate).